# Model of a body - center of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have to model a so called "seven-body-mechanism".
[image]

Looking in detail at K5

[image]

Is it possible to model the body "K5" as a straight body with the center of mass at (ta/tb)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well given your [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479370/seven-body-mechanism-in-modelica) about the same thing, have you tried it?